Is it possible to change the order of the X-Axis variables on R studios?
I am working on my Rstudios, where I am trying to find the relationship between the dependent variable (continuous): authoritarianism (0-7) and the independent Variable: praying. I have made it as far as producing the following graph, however it is not in the order I wanted it. I got this data from gss.csv with many different variables and I pick and choose which factors I want to test out. Here is how I want my variables in my x axis to be arranged: 1. Never, 2. LT once a week (less than once a week), 3. Once a week, 4. Several times a week, 5. Once a day, 6. Several times a day.
Im not sure how to do it.
In the image you can see what the graph i got was
